# Problem with recreating python b64encode and hmac function in C#

Tags: python, c#, hmac, hmacsha256

I have to create a function that generates exactly the same signature as it does in python. Here is my code

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_secret = 'aasfeef422c2dsa84fe9e7f56e6f214b'
    client_key_id = 'PHFg6w5XwnIYasDvdkqSjA=='
    nonce = 'fb807056-0d41-4c55-aa65-598a600bfe49'
    timestamp = '2022-04-01T06:57:50.280Z'

    signature = b64encode(hmac.new(b64decode(client_secret), msg=bytes(client_key_id + nonce + timestamp, 'utf-8'),
                                   digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode('utf-8')
```

value of signature here is: `'eenCmMzL12aPGat2zouBCaQQh9dC+8mJsm1KNpYQmOs='`

I have written down a C# function and the code looks like this:

```
        private static string Base64Encode(string text)
        {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }

        private static string GetHMAC(string text, string key)
        {
            key = key ?? "";

            using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)))
            {
                var hash = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
                return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client_secret = "aasfeef422c2dsa84fe9e7f56e6f214b";
            var client_key_id = "PHFg6w5XwnIYasDvdkqSjA==";
            var nonce = "fb807056-0d41-4c55-aa65-598a600bfe49";
            var timestamp = "2022-04-01T06:57:50.280Z";

            var hmac = GetHMAC(client_key_id + nonce + timestamp, Base64Encode(client_secret));
            var signature = Base64Encode(hmac);   
        }
```

unfortunately here the value of signature is `"dklPYzdlOEhjS1pZaU1UdkYweWRGZTRhZkFvUEF6djhiMUxpMFZOL2x1Yz0="`

and this is a huge difference. Do you have any idea how I can fix that problem, and make the C# algorithm generate the same signature, as the python algorithm ?

Comment: You may want to remove the sensitive parts of your question, like secrets.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid They aren't the original secrets

Comment: Why do you have a function Base64Encode that takes a string parameter while the actual data is probably something like byte[]? Why don't you call ToBase64String directly in the last line?

Comment: @jps could you give an example ?

Comment: I mean just the last line `var signature = Base64Encode(hmac);` , replace the call with ToBase64String

Comment: There look to be a number of issues, one being that you're performing a base64 **en**coding in C# where you're performing a **de**coding in python (e.g. `b64decode(client_secret)` vs. `Base64Encode(client_secret)`)

Comment: Well it still gives some error

Comment: ... and a double base64 conversion of the hash (GetHMAC returns a Base64 converted hash and in main you convert again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your C# code, including performing repeated Base64 encodings of the same data. The correct code is relatively simple:

```cs
private static string GetHMAC(string text, byte[] key)
{
    using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(key))
    {
        var hash = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client_secret = "aasfeef422c2dsa84fe9e7f56e6f214b";
    var client_key_id = "PHFg6w5XwnIYasDvdkqSjA==";
    var nonce = "fb807056-0d41-4c55-aa65-598a600bfe49";
    var timestamp = "2022-04-01T06:57:50.280Z";

    var hmac = GetHMAC(client_key_id + nonce + timestamp, Convert.FromBase64String(client_secret));
    Console.WriteLine(hmac);
}
```

This outputs `eenCmMzL12aPGat2zouBCaQQh9dC+8mJsm1KNpYQmOs=` as expected